# How can I set an item in Content Picker outside of AdminUI?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have `ContentTypeA` with a `ContentPickerA` field. I also have `ContentTypeB` with other fields, etc. These are created in a `Migrations.cs` file, which currently is the only code (other than the Workflow Activity below) in my module. So, no parts, drivers, etc.

I am in the process of creating a Worfklow that, after the user registers, will create `ContentItem1` off of `ContentTypeA`, and `ContentItem2` off of `ContentTypeB`.

I'd like to automatically link the content items, such that I am filling in `ContentPickerA` with `ContentItem2`. The point being to avoid having to go into AdminUI to manually link these items.

I've searched for quite a bit and have not been able to find any concrete examples, let alone anything that puts me on the right track.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Execute` of an Activities class I was able to get this working with the following code:

```
public override IEnumerable<LocalizedString> Execute(WorkflowContext workflowContext, ActivityContext activityContext)
    {
        LocalizedString outcome = null;

        try
        {
            //VARIABLES: DATA
            var mainTitle = "Test Content Title From Workflow Activity";
            var matterTitle = "Matter Type Title From Workflow Activity";

            //VARIABLES: NEW CONTENT ITEMS 
            var spacesMain = _contentManager.New("TestContentType");
            var spacesMatter = _contentManager.New("MatterType");

            //BIND DATA
            spacesMain.As<TitlePart>().Title = mainTitle;
            spacesMatter.As<TitlePart>().Title = matterTitle;

            //CREATE DRAFT CONTENT ITEMS
            _contentManager.Create(spacesMain, VersionOptions.Published);
            _contentManager.Create(spacesMatter, VersionOptions.Published);

            //SET CONTENT PICKER
            var contentPickerTest1 = ((dynamic)spacesMain).TestContentType.ContentPickerTest1;
            contentPickerTest1.Ids = new[] { spacesMatter.Id };

            outcome = T("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            workflowContext.SetState("Exception", exc);

            outcome = T("Error");
        }

        yield return outcome;

    }
```

Hope this helps someone, because as a non-programmer I was pretty glad to have finally seen the Content Item in the AdminUI have the ContentPickerField set to the other Content Item I created.